# SQLAlchemy Date and Time columns returned as InstrumentedAttribute

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have read in other questions that InstrumentedAttribute is something to do with a relationship, but if you look at my code below, `start_date` is not a relationship column. When I try to use `self.start_date` or `self.start_time` in the `start_datetime()` property, they are both `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute` objects and I can't find any way to get a date or time. I am using Python 3.4.3, SQLAlchemy 1.0.12, psycopg2 2.6.1, and postgresql 9.3.12

```
Base = declarative_base()

class OnetimeReservation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'OnetimeReservation'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    resource_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Resource.id', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'))
    job_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    start_date = Column(Date)
    start_time = Column(Time, nullable=True)
    duration = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    date_created = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    created_by = Column(String(128), server_default=text('CURRENT_USER'))
    date_last_modified = Column(DateTime, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'), server_onupdate=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    last_modified_by = Column(String(128), server_default=text('CURRENT_USER'), server_onupdate=text('CURRENT_USER'))

    resource = relationship('Resource')

    @hybrid_property
    def start_datetime(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.start_date, self.start_time)
```

Comment: thats very strange, `start_date`/ `start_time` should be <Date> and <Time> instances, by the way: `start_time` allows nulls and `datetime.combine` will crash if you don't give it a <Time>, example: `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2001,1,1), None)` -> `combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not None`

Comment: Thanks Javier, I might have caught the null issue if I could ever run my unit tests :-)

Comment: LOL. Out of curiosity, what is the output of `type(self)` inside your `start_datetime()`? Have you tried adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` (or `ipdb` if you're a true gansta') inside that function to see what is is exactly you're getting?

Comment: I'm running it with the debugger in PyCharm so, not a true gangsta' :-)
It says self is `<class scheduler.models.OnetimeReservation>`
....hmm....class, not an object. I'll bet that's my problem.  So why am I getting the class?  I guess it's something to do with `@hybrid_property`.  The docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid) don't mention getting a class

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong. The docs say "may receive self as an instance of the class, or as the class itself".

Answer (score 1):

After a more thorough reading of [the docs regarding hybrid_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), I think I know what's going on. The reason it is called a "hybrid" property is that is may be called with an instance of the class, or the class itself.  When used as filter parameter, it is called with the class itself and, it appears that there is an attempt to convert the code to SQL. There is a way to provide a separate implementation for `@start_time.expression` that will get called with the class. Thanks to everyone's help, I was able to work out a simple implementation that seems to work.  Here is the result:

```
@hybrid_property
def start_datetime(self):
    if not self.start_time:  # start_time can be null
        return None
    return datetime.combine(self.start_date, self.start_time)

@start_datetime.expression
def start_datetime(cls):
    return cls.start_date + cls.start_time
```

Comment: Cant you check for the instance? and do your code, and if its a class handle it another way?

Comment: I'm looking into that but I  need to make SQLAlchemy generate sql that looks something like this:  `('2012-10-29'|| ' ' || '10:19')::timestamp` and I'm still working out how to do that

Comment: I see: can you just do `return self.start_date + self.start_time` if its a class and do your code if its an instance?

Comment: Or look at this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html `hybrid_property` has a `expression` for the `cls`

Comment: the `expression` method is what I am trying to work out.  Just adding the two didn't work. It looks like I need to return a Function object and make sure its type is set to datetime or Timestamp

Comment: Adding a `date` and a `time` together should work in [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html). What error are you getting when you try?

Comment: I didn't get an error this time. I must have had something else going on when I tried it before. Thanks, univerio!