# SQLAlchemy filter by combined date and time with timezone

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, filter, sqlalchemy, timezone

**Update**

```
@datetime_as_timestamp.expression
def datetime_as_timestamp(cls):
    return db.func.timestamp(cls.date, cls.time)
```

to

```
@datetime_as_timestamp.expression
def datetime_as_timestamp(cls):
    return cls.date + cls.time
```

**Original**

I have date and time in my model. In the other table there is their timezone, but here for simplicity I'll do it manually. I want to filter by date + time + timezone.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    time = db.Column(db.Time)

    @hybrid_property
    def datetime_as_timestamp(self):
        return time.mktime(
            datetime.datetime.combine(self.date, self.time).timetuple()
        )

    @datetime_as_timestamp.expression
    def datetime_as_timestamp(cls):
        return db.func.timestamp(cls.date, cls.time)
```

But when I execute filter query

```
In [1]: Foo.query.filter(func.timezone('Australia/Brisbane', Foo.datetime_as_timestamp) <= func.timezone('UTC', func.current_timestamp())).one()
```

I get an error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "foo"
LINE 3: WHERE timezone('Australia/Brisbane', timestamp(foo.da...
                                                  ^
 [SQL: 'SELECT foo.id AS checkin_flight_id, foo.date AS checkin_flight_date, foo.time AS checkin_flight_time \nFROM foo \nWHERE timezone(%(timezone_1)s, timestamp(foo.date, foo.time)) <= timezone(%(timezone_2)s, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'] [parameters: {'timezone_2': 'UTC', 'timezone_1': 'Australia/Brisbane'}]
```

What am I missing, where is my mistake? Is it possible to solve my problem in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352258/sqlalchemy-date-and-time-columns-returned-as-instrumentedattribute) very helpful. I changed

```
@datetime_as_timestamp.expression
def datetime_as_timestamp(cls):
    return db.func.timestamp(cls.date, cls.time)
```

to

```
@datetime_as_timestamp.expression
def datetime_as_timestamp(cls):
    return cls.date + cls.time
```

and all works fine